# How to compile my java program (WordCount) for Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to compile my first MapReduce program : WordCount

Here is my WordcountMapper class:

```
package wordcount;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text,     IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();

        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }

    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        setup(context);
        while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
            map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
        }
        cleanup(context);
    }
}
```

I also have WordCountReducer and WordCountDriving classes.
The I try to compile everything with the command:

```
javac -classpath $HADOOP_CLASSPATH WordCount*.java
```

But the result is quite unexpected :

```
WordCountMapper.java:23: error: <identifier> expected
    Public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          ^
WordCountMapper.java:23: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    Public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                ^
WordCountMapper.java:25: error: ';' expected
        String line = value.toString()
                                      ^
WordCountMapper.java:27: error: ';' expected
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line)
                                                             ^
WordCountMapper.java:35: error: illegal start of expression
    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ^
WordCountMapper.java:35: error: illegal start of expression
    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
           ^
WordCountMapper.java:35: error: ';' expected
    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                   ^
WordCountMapper.java:35: error: ';' expected
    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                                   ^
WordCountMapper.java:35: error: not a statement
    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                                            ^
WordCountMapper.java:35: error: ';' expected
    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                                                       ^
WordCountMapper.java:35: error: not a statement
    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                                                         ^
WordCountMapper.java:35: error: ';' expected
    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                                                                               ^
```

12 errors

The problem is that I don't understand the errors it is giving me, it is like it doesn't see the ";" and I tried to re-write it but nothing changes

Comment: Your error doesn't match your source code, are you sure your specifying the correct path to the source file?

Comment: Yes, I only have one WordCountMapper file so the path is good as it can read it but the error sent is weird

Comment: Your error says that you have an `public` somewhere that starts with an uppercase (should be lowercase), and some lines that don't end with a semicolon

Comment: But how would it even be possible as I don't have any other WordCountMpper file?

Comment: Seems to be really strange that some errors do not match the source code. Did you try compiling other classes one by one instead of WordCount*. Also, if you can post other 2 classes as well, it might give us some hint.